# Alternative to DINPro Bold, Light and Medium for use on web

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation

I am looking for alternative fonts to use on a web site that are similar to DINPro Bold, Light and Medium.

They don't have to be free fonts, but can be through a service such as TypeKit or Fonts.com.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind posting a screenshot of DINPro?

Answer (score 2):

**Not an exact match but the feel is quite similar**.

1. Wire One - http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Wire+One

   1. Abel - http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Abel
   2. Here's a bolder version inspired by DIN:

ROPA SANS - http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Ropa+Sans

1. https://typekit.com/fonts/gesta

Answer (score 1):

Google Fonts has PT Sans by ParaType
https://www.google.com/fonts
[image: PT Sans]

[image: Din Pro]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is widely used in Germany and for that reason they were allowed to remake their own version which is nearly identical.  I can't remember where I heard that but here is the alternate version.

https://www.1001fonts.com/alte-din-1451-mittelschrift-font.html

Comment: Font is standardized in DIN 1415 standard  so that people can reproduce the same letters in anything. So the shapes are owned by din and you can just buy or lend the rules from a library.